# delete punctuation letter using strip function (Python)

Tags: python, strip, punctuation

```
import sys
import string
N, X = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
A = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())) 
B = []
for i in range(N-1):
    if(A[i]<X):
        B.append(A[i])
B = str(B)
B = B.strip(string.punctuation)
print(B)
```

the input was like this :

> 10 5
>
> 1 10 4 9 2 3 8 5 7 6

I do casting list B as a string and used strip function to delete punctuation
but the result of this code was like this with the comma:

```
1, 4, 2, 3
```

I checked there is a comma in punctuation letter in the String module

> !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~

I changed strip function like this but still didn't work
    B = B.strip(string.punctuation + ',')

I already deleted comma by adding the replace function, but I wonder why strip function didn't work

Comment: `strip` only removes chars from the beginning and end of the string. You want to use `replace`. BTW, a more common way of converting a list to a string is just `B = ' '.join(B)`

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. thaks